# Save all files locally on server when shiny app is closed

Tags: r, shiny, save

does somebody know if there is a way of saving the whole environment (or at least output objects) on the server calculated during the shiny session **in the moment the app is closed**. So as some kind of backup on the server if the user closes the app before downloading the results with a download button? So consider the simple example below where I even dont have a download button. How can I save the plot and the table output in one file, perfectly like the `save.image("file.RData")` function in a normal R session and with the additional condition that it saves when the app is closed.

```
ui=fluidPage(
  headerPanel('Iris k-means clustering'),
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput('xcol', 'X Variable', names(iris)),
    selectInput('ycol', 'Y Variable', names(iris),
                selected=names(iris)[[2]]),
    numericInput('clusters', 'Cluster count', 3,
                 min = 1, max = 9)
  ),
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput('plot1'),
    dataTableOutput('table1')
  )
)



server=function(input, output, session) {

  # Combine the selected variables into a new data frame
  selectedData <- reactive({
    iris[, c(input$xcol, input$ycol)]
  })

  clusters <- reactive({
    kmeans(selectedData(), input$clusters)
  })

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    palette(c("#E41A1C", "#377EB8", "#4DAF4A", "#984EA3",
              "#FF7F00", "#FFFF33", "#A65628", "#F781BF", "#999999"))

    par(mar = c(5.1, 4.1, 0, 1))
    plot(selectedData(),
         col = clusters()$cluster,
         pch = 20, cex = 3)
    points(clusters()$centers, pch = 4, cex = 4, lwd = 4)
  })
  output$table1 <- renderDataTable(iris)
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Any ideas?
Many thanks.

Comment: Hum, I wonder if `on.exit` as the last line of `server()` would work here?

Comment: `session$onSessionEnded(function() {})` is the usual way to go,...

Comment: First of all many thanks. But can you give an example or adapt it on the example in the question? I tried session$onSessionEnded(function() {save.image("file.RData")}) but this did not work. Additionally it has to save the data only of the current shiny session of the user that closes the app and not everything in the workspace for the case more than one person are using the app at the same time- just came to my mind if this would be problematic. .

Comment: are you using shiny server?

Comment: the app should run on a server that I own and all colleagues could use the app via their computers. For the case they forgot to download their data there should be a backup of results saved on my server, so I could send them the results on request.